# Rocket move through class. Processing

Tags: java, processing

I have a moving image as a background

```
PImage background;
int x=0; //global variable background location
rocket Rocket;

void setup(){
 size(800,400);
 background = loadImage("spaceBackground.jpg");
 background.resize(width,height);
 Rocket = new rocket();
}

void draw ()
{
 image(background, x, 0); //draw background twice adjacent
 image(background, x+background.width, 0);
 x -=4;
 if(x == -background.width)
 x=0; //wrap background
 Rocket.defender();
 Rocket.move();
}
```

In a different class i'm trying to make a rocket move up and down

```
class rocket {
  float x;
  float y;
  float speedy;
  boolean up;
  boolean down;

 rocket(){
   x = 50;
   y = 200;
   speedy = 3;
 }

void move() {
 if(up)
 {
  y = y - speedy;
 }
 if(down)
 {
  y = y + speedy;
 }
} 

void defender(){
 fill(255,0,0);
 rect(x,y,50,20);
 triangle(x+50,y,x+50,y+20,x+60,y+10);
 fill(0,0,100);
 rect(x,y-10,20,10);
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP)
  {
   up = true;
  }
  if(keyCode == DOWN)
  {
   down = true;
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  if(keyCode == UP)
  {
   up = false;
  }
  if(keyCode == DOWN)
  {
   down = false;
  }
}   
}
```

The rocket will display but won't move. I tried everything I know but nothing works. I also tried the rocket class just as a project by itself and the rocket moves, so it has to be something with the class. i'm quite new to coding so please keep that in mind, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` functions (and any other event function) need to be at the sketch level, not inside another class. If they're inside another class, Processing doesn't know how to find them.

So, what you need to do is move the `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` functions to the sketch, and then call functions on your `Rocket` class (class names should start with an upper-case letter, btw), similar to how you're calling `rocket.defender()` and `rocket.move()` (variable names should start with a lower-case letter) from the sketch-level `draw()` function.

Comment: also, do you know how can i restrict the rocket so it wont get out the screen while i move it up and down ?

Comment: @AlexandrosConstantinides Sure, you can just use `if` statements to restrict when you move your rocket. I've written a tutorial on animation in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation), which includes limiting your animation to stay inside the screen. If you still can't get it working, please post a [mcve] (not your whole sketch, just a single rectangle that moves with the arrow keys) in a new question and we'll go from there. Good luck.